# How can I make my recording sound louder in Audacity?

Tags: audio, microphone

I record how-to videos and I get a pretty decent, loud sound. But I'd like to make it a bit louder without clipping. Anyway to do this?

MY SETUP
Analog mixer
Behringer XM8500 dynamic mic
I use Audacity to tweak and clean up my audio.

Comment: Does the `Effect -> Amplify` do what you want?

Answer (score 3):

Try the Effect->Compressor.

> The Compressor effect reduces the dynamic range of audio. One of the
>   main purposes of reducing dynamic range is to permit the audio to be
>   amplified further (without clipping) than would be otherwise possible,

as stated here: http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Compressor

Answer (score 0):

the other thing is to get a mic with a DB meter, so you can choose to record louder for example the SE Electronics condenser mic

Comment: Having a meter doesn't allow you to record any louder.  Or did you mean something else?